# Vue.js: change parent variable from multiple layer down

Tags: vue.js

This is my `Vue Instance`:

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
        return {
            loading: false
        }
    },
    components: { 
        App,
        Loading
    },
    router,store,
})
```

How can I change the `loading` variable from multiple layer down? It's not just simple parent/child change. It can be greatgrandparent/child change too.

Comment: use vuex for that

Comment: use event system may easier. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html

Comment: eventbus https://reactgo.com/vuejs-eventbus-example/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options, but the best way to answer the questions is to register as a global plug-in.

See the following solutions:

1. Create loading component and register it as a Vue component.

```
// loadingDialog.vue
<template>
<!-- ... -->
</template>

<script>
import { Loading } from 'path' // Insert the `loading` declared in number 2.

export default {
 beforeMount () {
   Loading.event.$on('show', () => {
     this.show()
   })
 },
 methods: {
   show () {}
 }
}
</script>
```

2. Creating a global plug-in

```
const loading = {
 install (Vue, opt = {}) {
  let constructor = Vue.extend(LOADING_COMPONENT)
  let instance = void 0

  if (this.installed) {
    return
  }

  this.installed = true

  Vue.prototype.$loadingDialog = {
    show () {
      if (instance) {
        instance.show()  // function of loading component
        return
      }

      instance = new constructor({
        el: document.createElement('div')
      })

      document.body.appendChild(instance.$el)
      instance.show()  // function of loading component
    }
  }
 }
}
```

3. All components are accessible through the prototype.

```
this.$loadingDialog.show() // or hide()
```

---

Note, it is recommended that you control the api communication using the axios in the `request or response interceptor`of the axios at once.

Comment: Where to place the `const loading`?

Comment: Create a vue instance or place it after inserting it. Because it is a plug-in, use it after Vue.use, the same as using the Vue plug-in.